# как через js выбрать select , чтобы сработало событие change и поддянулись города?

Tags: javascript

при открытии страницы  для редактировании нужно чтобы были выбраны области и города которые были сохраннены
т.е к примеру при редактировании
$areas = 2160 ; $city = 117 ;

пробовал сделать так:

```js
.then(
        ()=>{
            var area = 'a2160';
            var elem = document.getElementById(area);
            elem.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
         
        }
        
    )
выбирает область но города не появляются в списке городов
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//выаодить все области
    let dataList = {};
    fetch("https://api.hh.ru/areas/5").then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(
            json => {
                dataList = json;
                json.areas.forEach(area => {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = area.id;
                    opt.setAttribute("id", "a" +area.id);
                    opt.innerHTML = area.name;
                    billing_area.appendChild(opt);
                }
                );
            }
    );
         // подтягивает города выбранной области   
    billing_area.addEventListener('change', () => {
        billing_city.innerHTML = '';
        dataList.areas.filter(item => item.id == billing_area.options[billing_area.selectedIndex].value)[0].areas.forEach(
                area => {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = area.id;
                    opt.innerHTML = area.name;
                    billing_city.appendChild(opt);
                }
        )

    });
</script>
```

```html
<select name="area" id="billing_area" class="country_to_state city_select " autocomplete="city">
        <option id="changearea"value="">Выбрать область</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="billing_city" class="country_to_state city_select " autocomplete="city" required>
 <option value="">Выбрать город</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var area = '2160';
        billing_area.value = area;
        billing_area.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Comment: это куда вставить? что-то не сработало

Comment: @junior Туда где `var area = 'a2160';`.

Comment: туда вставлял не сработало даже не выбрало

Comment: @junior Я не знаю, как Вы вставляли.

Comment: .then(
        ()=>{
            var area = 'a2160';
            billing_area.value = area;
            billing_area.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        }
        
    );

вставил после первого .then

Comment: @junior `var area = '2160';`

Comment: убрал букву "а" заработало, спасибо